# Yii2 full calendar AjaxEvents not working properly

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Hi everyone i am using [this extension](https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar) in my project and i am having problem with the `ajaxEvents`,i want to know what is wrong i am doing here?? Here is my code of view file and controller action

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <?= yii2fullcalendar::widget([
        'events' => $events,
        'options' => [
            'language' => 'en',
            'eventLimit' => 2,
        ],
        'ajaxEvents' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/jsoncalendar'])
    ]);
    ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And here is the controller code

```
 public function actionJsoncalendar($start=NULL,$end=NULL,$_=NULL){

    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $times = Event::find()->where(1)->all();

    $events = array();

    foreach ($times AS $time){
        //Testing
        $Event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
        $Event->id = $time->id;
        $Event->title = $time->title;
        $Event->start = $time->start_time;
        $Event->end = $time->end_time;
        $events[] = $Event;
    }

    return $events;
}
```

Tried using `eventLimit` as well but thats not working either

Comment: Please provide link to extension that you are using.

Comment: @arogachev added the link

Comment: In `ajaxEvents` you specified url containing only action name, have you tried to specify it like with controller / module id like mentioned in the README: `'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(['/timetrack/default/jsoncalendar'])`?

Comment: @arogachev yes i have and still giving error. I dropped using that widget anyway because it has many other issues and its github is also not updating the version. Thank you for your help anyway

Comment: Maybe it's in initial stage of development.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same extension and I found out (at least in my project) that ajaxEvents should return a encoded JSON array. Try to return:

```
return json_encode($events);
```

And delete this line:

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```